# Best way to include wp-config.php

Tags: plugins, wp-config

I was wondering what way is the best to include wp-config.php into a plugin.
I have read about relative paths that can fail if the plugin files are situated somewhere else.

Comment: Are you actually talking about a WordPress plugin or are you trying to load WordPress from an external file?

Comment: If you modify your question to be more specific to your actual problem, then you might get better answers.

Comment: I had problems using $wpdb in my plugin, I saw an example that used include wp-config. I will try again with $wpdb

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way is to not do that. There's no need for a plugin file to ever include the wp-config.php.

You're doing it backwards. WordPress loads plugins. Plugins don't load WordPress.

Comment: There are valid reasons to include wp-config.php. For example for plugins that receive notification from APIs, a callback file can include the config file to access the database. In this case, making the callback file be loaded from Wordpress is an awful practice.

Comment: You are wrong. This answere is maybe true if you write some half-assed hello-world plugin aka 'create a nice textarea on the frontend'. What if you actually write a big software and need to have automatic Unit-Tests? My shell loads a UnitTest inside my Plugin, no wordpress-core or functionality. Options reach between symlinking, absolute path inclusion or Symfony style namespaces, but you'd have to mod the core-file

Answer (score 0):

`wp-config.php` should always already be loaded, and should not need to be included.

In most cases, the best way to ensure `$wbdp` is included in your plugin and theme functions is to ensure your theme and plugin files are found in the correct location and your plugin or theme is active.

If `global $wpdb` is not yet set, then you shouldn't need to include any core WordPress files. It most likely means your function is just being fired too early, and you should place it inside an action, such as `muplugins_loaded`, `plugins_loaded`, `after_setup_theme`, `init`, or `wp_loaded`.

If you have a separate file that you use like an ajax request, then you should switch it out and use the WordPress ajax hooks instead.

The only valid time I've found to include `wp-config.php` is to expand upon the common `if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;`, so that users are redirected home when they attempt to access any of my theme or plugin files / directories directly.

```
<?php
/**
 * Silence is golden, but I actually want people to view the website.
 */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    // Call dirname() 4 times as this file is in '/wp-contents/plugins/plugin-dir/' and wp-config.php is in '/'
    require_once dirname( dirname( dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) ) ) . '/wp-config.php';
    // Permanent redirect home.
    wp_safe_redirect( home_url(), 301 );
    die;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

If you only want access to `wp-config.php` without the rest of the WordPress functions.

Do the following steps:

1. create a empty `wp-settings.php` file in your plugin directory
2. ad this to your PHP file

   ```
   define( 'ABSPATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/plugins/YOUR_PLUGIN_DIR/' ); 
   require_once( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-config.php' );
   ```

This works perfect for WordPress 4.2.4 "down and up" and I tested it in our own plugin mywebapplets.

Comment: As [@Otto said](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/159348/22534) this should not be done.

Comment: Actually not a bad start, but it won't work with the Wordpress installed under a subdirectory.